# Apache rewrite for particular file requests

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to setup Apache to rewrite particular file names when requested under a virtual host. The goal is to change certain branding elements based on the host header used (all of which have virtual host configs).

I had this working in nginx as per the example below

```
if ($host = "test.example.com") {
    rewrite ^/images/file1.png$ /images/otherfile1.png;
    rewrite ^/images/file2.png$ /images/differentfile2.png;
    break;
}
```

For Apache I used the following config in the virtual hosts file, and confirmed the module is running, but it does not seem work (the original file1 is used).

```
<Directory "/opt/site/html/">
     AllowOverride All
     Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     Require all granted
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^/images/file1.png$ /images/otherfile1.png
   RewriteRule ^/images/file2.png$ /images/differnetfile2.png
   </Directory>
```

Any advice on what I'm missing to enable this rewrite would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/images/file1.png$ /images/otherfile1.png
> RewriteRule ^/images/file2.png$ /images/differnetfile2.png
> ```

These directives are inside a `<Directory>` container (inside a `<VirtualHost>`). In a *directory* context (as with `.htaccess`), the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash. So the above rules will not match. The directives should be like this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^images/file1\.png$ /images/otherfile1.png [L]
RewriteRule ^images/file2\.png$ /images/differnetfile2.png [L]
```

NB: Don't forget to backslash-escape literal dots in the regex and you should use the `L` flag here to stop further processing by the rewrite engine.

Alternatively, you can move these rules out of the `<Directory>` wrapper and into the `<VirtualHost>` container directly. In this context, the rules match against the full root-relative URL-path, starting with a slash (as you have written). But in a *virtualhost* context, the `RewriteBase` directive is not permitted so must be removed (you are not making use of this anyway).

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> AllowOverride All
> Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
> ```

You are allowing `.htaccess` overrides (first directive). Note that if you do have an `.htaccess` file with mod_rewrite directives (`RewriteRule` etc.) then these will completely override the directives in the corresponding `<Directory>` container in the server config. You may want to explicitly disable `.htaccess` overrides, for example:

```
AllowOverride None
```

You've also *enabled* `MultiViews` - is that intentional? This basically enables extensionless URLs out-of-the-box (on everything) and can potentially conflict with mod_rewrite, so generally, this should be *disabled*. Simply remove it from the above rule to disable this, for example:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
```

> ```
> RewriteBase /
> ```

You're not actually using this in the directives you've posted.

Comment: Thanks. I've made the changes suggested, removed the starting slash and backslash escape, and base. Also changed AllowOverride, but it does not seem to have had an effect. Is there anyway to check whats being applied/why its not rewriting?

Comment: @DanKennedy Have you restarted Apache? Cleared browser cache?

Comment: Yes, restarted service, cleared cache, tried incognito mode etc, no joy

Comment: @DanKennedy So, the file/URL you are requesting is located at `/opt/site/html/images/file1.png` and `/opt/site/html/` is the `DocumentRoot`? So you are requesting `example.com/images/file1.png` in the browser? You don't have a front-end proxy that serves static content?

Comment: Correct and yes no front-end proxy

Comment: Try a simple redirect... eg. `RewriteRule ^/?foo$ /bar [R,L]` (mod_rewrite) or`Redirect /foo /bar` (mod_alias) if the mod_rewrite directive does not work - are you redirected from `/foo` to `/bar`?